# Занесение ответа от запроса ajax в массив и вывод

Tags: javascript, ajax, массивы

Сформировал запрос ajax:

```
var holder = [];
var tutajax2 = $.ajax("otobr.php")
  .done(function(data) {
    $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, value) {
      holder["index" + key] = `${value.fname} ${value.sname} ${value.score}\n`;
    });
    console.log(holder);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("ne ochen");
  });
```

Получаю ответ в консоль в виде:

```
[index0: "Влад Кислюк 40↵", index1: "Влад Кислюк 38↵", index2: "Анатолий Анатольевич 33↵", index3: "Влад Кислюк 6↵", index4: "Влад Кислюк 2↵", …]
index0
:
"Влад Кислюк 40↵"
index1
:
"Влад Кислюк 38↵"
index2
:
"Анатолий Анатольевич 33↵"
index3
:
"Влад Кислюк 6↵"
index4
:
"Влад Кислюк 2↵"
index5
:
"Влад Кислюк 1↵"
index6
:
"Анатолий Анатольевич 1↵"
length
:
0
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

Пытаюсь вывести `holder` построчно (каждая запись с новой строки):

```
pjs.brush.drawTextLines({ 
  lines : [ 
  holder[0],
  holder[1],
  holder[2]
],  
  x : 20, y : 20,  
  color : "black"  
});
```

Но в ответ получаю 3 строки с надписью undefinded.

Вопрос: Как вывести мой массив из `holder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pjs.brush.drawTextLines({ 
  lines : [ 
  holder["index0"],
  holder["index1"],
  holder["index2"]
],  
  x : 20, y : 20,  
  color : "black"  
});
```